# Transform bad string format object into real object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

From a GET request to a service I receive a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "id": "SWKJHFDJHSDFLSVNDHLSDKJHNLSDLSDNVLKVSNLK",
  "payload": "{ att1: value1, att2: value2}"
}
```

When it should be like this:

```
{
  "id": "SWKJHFDJHSDFLSVNDHLSDKJHNLSDLSDNVLKVSNLK",
  "payload": { "att1": "value1", "att2": "value2"}
}
```

The problem is that the payload has a bad format for a JSON object, and I can't transform it into a real object with JSON.parse().

How can I transform `"{ att1: value1, att2: value2}"` into a real JavaScript object?

Comment: is the format always the same? i.e. could a regex find/replace work for you?

Comment: @atmd yes, the format is always the same, is a regular object of two attributes but inside quotes like a string `"{ a: a1, b: b1 }"`

Comment: a better question to ask is why your JSON is coming back like that in the first place...

Comment: @Mike its a bug in the service that the creators say they are too busy to fix right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the format is the same then you can use regex to insert the speach marks like this:

`"{ att1: value1, att2: value2}".replace(/([a-z0-9]+)/g,"'$1'");`

This will insert `'` around the key and values in the string.

so: `"{ att1: value1, att2: value2}".replace(/([a-z0-9]+)/g,"\"$1\"");`

**N.B.** You'll have to account for the possibility of single and/or double speach marks in the values of your input/api/json response.
gives `"{ "att1": "value1", "att2": "value2"}"`

the quotes must be double quotes `"` for json parse to work, so using json parse on the above will give you your object, in one line it's

```
var myObject = JSON.parse("{ att1: value1, att2: value2}".replace(/([a-z0-9]+)/g,"\"$1\""));
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it's still a string, not and object, and cannot be transformed into an object with JSON.parse().

Comment: It worked! First time in my life that a regex solves a problem instead of creating them.

Comment: glad I could help. sorry I didnt spot the double quote mistake earlyer, always forget json requires double quotes over single